# IntelliJ, Scala plugin and h2-browser

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, h2, playframework-2.2

Is there any way to add the `h2-browser` flag in a Play 2 IntelliJ run configuration? I prefer not to manually run `sbt` and / or and `sbt` console.